# _Free_base causes error for some unknown reason

Tags: c++, winapi

My program calls a function called _free_base but I don't have it on any part of my program. And when I debugged it, I found out that the error happened in the following snippet but I couldn't isolate the exact position :

```
HWND CreateComboBox(HWND hwnd, vector<Product> products, int charWidth, int charHeight)
{
  HWND result = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, TEXT(""),
      CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CHILD,
    102 + 2 * charWidth, (products.size() + 1) * charHeight, 
    100, 100, hwnd, NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

  for (unsigned int iii = 0; iii < products.size(); iii++)
  {
    ComboBox_AddString(result, products[iii].name);
  }

  ComboBox_SetCurSel(result, 0);

  return result;
}
```

That's the part of my program where the error happened. The VS call stack stated that the next function to be called is the `return result` part. Which means that it happened during `ComboBox_SetCurSel` right? But when I erased that part, the next function to be called is still `return result`. That's why I couldn't isolate the exact error position. On the call stack, the function above this one is this Microsoft file:

free.c

```
    void __cdecl _free_base (void * pBlock)
    {

      int retval = 0;


      if (pBlock == NULL)
          return;

      RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pBlock, 0));

      retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
      if (retval == 0)
      {
          errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
      }  
    }
```

And the error is at the `retval = HeapFree...`

Finally, the Output window in VS posted this `Unhandled exception at 0x77133873 (ntdll.dll) in Inventory Program.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x7714CDD8).`

I'm new here, so if you need any more information please just ask in the comments and don't rate down my question. Thanks.

Oh yes here's the Call Stack :

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@8()

ntdll.dll!_RtlpReportHeapFailure@4()    Unknown

ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown

ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12() Unknown

kernel32.dll!_HeapFree@12() Unknown

>msvcr120.dll!free(void * pBlock) Line 51

Inventory Program.exe!CreateComboBox(HWND__ * hwnd, std::vector<Product,std::allocator<Product> > products, int charWidth, int charHeight) Line 74

Inventory Program.exe!WndProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message,  unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 139  C++

[External Code] 

Inventory Program.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow) Line 48 C++

[External Code]
```

**EDIT :** Here's my Product class

product.h

```
#ifndef STOCK_H
#define STOCK_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

class Product
{
 public:
 TCHAR* name;
 double price;
 int stock;

 Product(string, double, int);

 ~Product();

 void sell(int sold);
 void stockup(int stocked);

};

void initProductList(vector<Product> &p_list);

void saveProductData(vector<Product> &p_list);

#endif
```

product.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "product.h"

using namespace std;

Product::Product(string a, double b, int c)
{
    const char* cStringForm = a.c_str();

    name = new TCHAR[strlen(cStringForm) + 1];

    name[a.size()] = 0;

    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), name);

    price = b;
    stock = c;
}

Product::~Product()
{
    delete[] name;
}

void Product::sell(int sold)
{
    stock -= sold;
}

void Product::stockup(int stocked)
{
    stock += stocked;
}

void initProductList(vector<Product> &p_list)
{
    //Fills the p_list vector with Product objects

    p_list.reserve(50);

    //There is no file which contains the amount of products
    //It is placed in the first line of the product_name_file
    ifstream product_name_file("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_names.txt");
    ifstream product_price_file("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_prices.txt");
    ifstream product_stock_file("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_stocks.txt");
    int product_quantity(0);
    product_name_file >> product_quantity;

    for (int iii = 0; iii < product_quantity; iii++)
    {
        string name;
        double price;
        int stock;

        product_name_file >> name;
        product_price_file >> price;
        product_stock_file >> stock;

        Product a(name, price, stock);

        p_list.push_back(a);
    }

    product_name_file.close();
    product_price_file.close();
    product_stock_file.close();

}

void saveProductData(vector<Product> &p_list)
{
    ofstream productName("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_names.txt", 
    ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
    ofstream productPrice("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_prices.txt",
    ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
    ofstream productStock("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\My Programs\\Projects\\Inventory Program\\product_stocks.txt",
    ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);

    productName << p_list.size() << "\n";

    for (unsigned int iii = 0; iii < p_list.size(); iii++)
    {
        productName << p_list[iii].name << "\n";
        productName.flush();
        productPrice << p_list[iii].price << "\n";
        productPrice.flush();
        productStock << p_list[iii].stock << "\n";
        productStock.flush();
    }
    productName.close();
    productPrice.close();
    productStock.close();
}
```

Comment: The bug is in your `Product` implementation. If you want to postpone the bug to a later point, pass a `const vector<Product>&` to your `CreateComboBox` method.

Comment: Your program is corrupting memory. Try running with application verifier or other memory checking debugging tools like valgrind.

Comment: @IInspectable The implementation as in the constructor?.

Comment: @IInspectable or is it because of the `TCHAR* name` ? Because I used `std::string` for my `name` variable type for my command line version of the program. But, I had to change it to TCHAR* because the functions provided by WinAPI needs them.

Comment: You violated the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). When you `push_back` the products into the vector, the default copy constructor is used, which eventually leads to a double-free bug when the vector is destructed.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'll try to create the copy constructor. Btw, thanks for the link. Never heard of that before. So, whenever I pass an argument by value the copy constructor is called. So, the problem is because the pointer is freed twice?

Comment: @RaymondChen your suggestion works! Thanks! Now I just have to finish another heap block problem in this program. Now I know why people hate memory management

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you sir! For this and helping me with your answer for another question! The one where the hwnd parameter in the message loop should be NULL. thanks!